# Divs are not on the same height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a page that has three `<div>`'s that should be next to each other and at the bottom of the page it should show a fourth `<div>`. All of that should be visible without scrolling, why I'm using 100vh and 100vw to just use the viewfield. but it puts all three `<divs>` on different heights.

It's going to be a HbbTV App, that's why it is important to be fullscreen.

```css
html,body { margin:0; padding: 0; }
#inputpanel {
  width: calc(40vw - 10px);
}
#selectpanel {
  width: calc(20vw - 10px);
}
#colorpanel {
  width: calc(40vw - 10px);
}
#inputpanel,#selectpanel,#colorpanel {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.b_footer {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.colorbuttons {
    background-color: #0000ff;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
 width: 30%;
 margin: 10px;
 
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--As DOCTYPE either the strict XHTML declaration or "-//HbbTV//1.1.1//EN" "http://www.hbbtv.org/dtd/HbbTV-1.1.1.dtd" shall be used as described in the HbbTV-standard: A.2.6.2.-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!--Required XML-namespace as described in the HbbTV-standard: A.2.6.2.-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head> <!--Required MIME content type as described in the HbbTV-standard: A.2.6.2.-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/vnd.hbbtv.xml+xhtml; utf-8" />
<!--script type="text/javascript" src="hueapi.js"/-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="DemoHbbtvHue.css"/>
<title>Demo for HbbTV and Hue</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="inputpanel">
  
Step1: Enter IP or use DummySystem.
<button type="button" id="dummy" onclick="enteringDummySystem()">DummySystem</button><br />
<br />
NOTE: Please press the button on your Hue-Bridge before clicking on "Search"<br />
IP: <input type="text" id="inIP" />
<button type="button" id="buIP" onclick="searchDevices('Lamp', 'Hue', document.getElementById('inIP').value)">Search</button><br />
<button type="button" id="getIds" onclick="getId()">Get Light IDs</button>
<button type="button" id="createBut" onclick="createButton(function(){
        alert('it works');})">create Button</button>

</div>

<div id="selectpanel">
gfsd

</div>

<div id="colorpanel">

<button type="button" class="colorbuttons" id="buttonSetColorWhite" onclick="setColor(0.1684,0.0416)">Blue</button><br />
<button type="button" class="colorbuttons" id="buttonSetColorRed" onclick="setColor(0.6549,0.3126)">Red</button><br />
<button type="button" class="colorbuttons" id="buttonSetColorWhite" onclick="setColor()">White</button><br />
<button type="button" class="colorbuttons" id="buttonSetColorRed" onclick="setColor()">Green</button><br />
<button type="button" class="colorbuttons" id="buttonSetColorWhite" onclick="setColor()">Yellow</button><br />
<button type="button" class="colorbuttons" id="buttonSetColorRed" onclick="setColor()">Pink</button><br />

</div>

<div class="b_footer">
 This demo provides the possibility to control Philips Hue lamps via a HbbTV-Application.
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

What could I change to achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are looking to do is get all elements in the viewport without any scrolling (and get the top three divs the same height), you can add `overflow: hidden;` to `#inputpanel,#selectpanel,#colorpanel` styles. This does push the content on the first two divs to the top of that element though.

However, I would recommend using Flexbox to solve for a number of positioning issues you may encounter if that is a possibility.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Here is a starting point if you were to go the Flexbox route:

First, you will need to wrap you top three div's in another `div`. Something like `<div class="top-container">` - see styles added to `top-container` below.

```
html,body { 
  margin:0; 
  padding: 0; 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.top-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: calc(100vh - 200px);
}
#inputpanel {
  width: calc(40vw - 10px);
}
#selectpanel {
  width: calc(20vw - 10px);
}
#colorpanel {
  width: calc(40vw - 10px);
}
#inputpanel,#selectpanel,#colorpanel {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.b_footer {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.colorbuttons {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: that did the trick. creating a top-container would have been a good first step from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You could use floats and add width of 100% to footer:

```
#inputpanel,#selectpanel,#colorpanel {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: calc(100vh - 200px);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.b_footer {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[JFiddle example here.](https://jsfiddle.net/ykjbt6ru/)